# how to implement reverse proxy to download a setup in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have tried with the below code but it dosent work

```
server{
    listen:80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_pass         http://example1.com/;
    }
}
```

published url of setup is  : http://example.com/setup.exe
and setup can be download from http://example1.com/setup.exe

Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Remove the `proxy_set_header Host $host;` line.

Answer (score 0):

removed both "proxy_set_header" and issue has been fixed.